# How to debug pending state of an HTTP request

Tags: http, iis

My website works fine on my local machine. And it also works fine, when I publish it, and access it over the Internet.

However, when I access it through my company's network (LAN), many requests state in the *pending* state and they won't return back either successfully, or with error. No IIS logs, no nothing.

After like 5 minutes, the request simply dies. No HTTP response is shown in Chrome's console. I guess it's a network problem. But I don't know how to debug it.

How should I debug this *pending* state?

Comment: check out fiddler tool it might be simple

Comment: No HTTP request @cpoDesign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a problem for sys-ops than for development but you might need to verify/prove the problem is with the routers and not with your server or computer configuration.

The first tool you need is network analyzer, for this look no further than [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). You'll need administrator permissions on your machine.
Wireshark is intuitive, but has a lot of features, you might want to read a tutorial or two on how to use it.

With Wireshark on your machine you can verify a TCP connection to the server is made or attempted. If you don't know how TCP works, now is the time to learn.
Based on the result you should have your answer of where the problem is:

- No TCP SYN sent or sent to wrong IP: problem in your machine. Make sure the server is not redirected to localhost/wrong ip in the hosts file and verify no static routes have been added to your routing table.
- Most likely no TCP SYN-ACK: The problem is in the network routing, you might want to install Wireshark on the server and verify the SYN packets are indeed not getting through. Get your sys-ops guys to fix the problem. Probably a misconfigured firewall rule.
- Very unlikely: TCP connection established and HTTP request sent to server, but server does not respond. No idea, if the server responds to internet traffic it should respond to your traffic.

By the way if there are no sys-ops guys in your company to fix the problem, get the model of any configurable router between your computer and the server and try asking in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (or get a consultant).